# Reinitialize iscroll

Tags: javascript, html, iscroll

I am using iScroll4 for my project (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

As my container height changes I would need to reinitialize iscroll for a dom element. Is there anyway I could do that

e.g.

```
scroller.reset();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need the [`refresh()`](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4#refreshmethod) function:

> iScroll needs to know the correct dimensions of both the wrapper and
>   the scroller. They are computed the first time at start up but if your
>   code changes the elements size, iScroll needs to be warned that you
>   are messing with the DOM.
>
> This is achieved by calling the `refresh` function with the right
>   timing. Please follow me closely, understanding this will save you
>   hours of scrolling frustration.

You can use it as follows:

```
myScroll.refresh();
```

Where `myScroll` represents the variable to which you initialized iScroll.

Comment: Thank you ! Just what I wanted to know. Giving it a shot now, will let you know.

Comment: Hey Ben. Since you so easily helped me with my query. I have another one that I could not find the answer to. Does iScroll have any trigger when the scroll reaches to the end ? Or no "onscroll" events ?

Comment: I guess I found it "onScrollEnd". Thanks Ben !